# How to remove directory from rsync share completely

Tags: linux, rsync

Is there any rsync command that can remove some remote directory from rsync share completely? I mean delete not only directory content but the directory itself. And without rsyncing the entire parent directory since it can be very large.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Can you show some more detail about your setup and rsync command?

Comment: Assume that we have a remote server that has one share. There are some directories in the share. Let `x` be one of them. I want a single rsync command that can delete `x` recursively and completely like `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question...
In fact it is possible to remove directory from the remote server completely (including directory itself). Check the example below:

```
rsync -r --delete --include 'x/***' --exclude '*' local_empty_directory/ rsync://some_server/some_share/x_parent_directory
```

The key is to clean the parent directory for `x` (`x_parent_directory` in example) using local empty directory `local_empty_directory` while excluding everything by using `--exclude '*'` and including only the directory we want to delete (`x` in example) and its content by `--include 'x/***'`.

Answer (score 1):

Following man of rsync you can use --exclude

> --exclude=PATTERN
>
> This  option is a simplified form of the --filter option that defaults to an exclude rule and does not allow the full rule-pars-ing syntax of normal filter rules.
>
> --exclude-from=FILE
>
> This option is related to the --exclude option, but it specifies a FILE that contains exclude patterns (one  per  line).   Blank
>                 lines in the file and lines starting with ';' or '#' are ignored.  If FILE is -, the list will be read from standard input.

Comment: I do not understand your solution completely. It looks like I should run `rsync --list-only` to get a list of directories and then use exclude pattern that excludes everything except the directory I want to delete. If I am correct then this solution contains 2 subsequent rsync calls. I want to use only one rsync invocation to avoid concurrent access issues as much as possible.

Comment: Ooops, my fault, I understood remove as not using it in rsync.

Comment: Actually this is OK since my question is badly formed. In fact I tried the 2 rsync invocation solution and it works fine except concurrent access issues and it looks like there is no better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove remote directories with rsync. The best you can do is to remove *all files* inside a remote directory, using the "--remove-source-files" option. From the man page:

> This  tells  rsync  to  remove  from  the sending side the files
>   (meaning non-directories) that are a part of  the  transfer  and have
>   been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

Alternatively, you could simply issue a rm command via SSH, for example:

> `ssh root@remote_ip -c "rm -rf /somedir"`

Comment: Looks like I did it, please review my answer.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you solved your problem. However, if you have SSH access to the remote server, why do not use the ssh -c method described above? It seems a more logical and direct solution...

Comment: Because I do not have ssh, only rsync

Comment: Fair enough. :)